# Is there a centric stylish approach like CSS for reporting services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, styles

Hi i been googling around and couldn't found any answer or approach to this issue, what i would like to accomplish is to hanlde all the styles, colors font sizes, etc from one place kinda like css does with html, been trying with microsoft tutorials but i don't see they cover this point in a satisfactory way, may the technology doesn't cover it at all...
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSRS 2005 if all your reports are going to be similar you could create your own template. This would take most of the workout of the initial set-up  as you can make a template with the style you need in (headers, footers, datatable etc).
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jhermiz/archive/2007/08/14/60283.aspx

You can also create templates in SSRS 2008 along with style templates which are XML files containing pre-defined styles.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/yanivy/archive/2010/08/03/create-custom-templates-and-styles-for-ssrs-2008.aspx

Comment: I end up using templates and a little project that injects styles into the rdl file...that is an xml file ;) with linq :)